# Distracting Red Icons in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: ide, typescript, visual-studio-2013

Visual Studio 2013 displays all my TypeScript files with a red icon:

[image: red icons]

I have no idea why they are <del>red</del> dark-orange (there are no errors and .cs/.json/etc. are fine) but I find that very distracting.

Can I make them black/green/anything-but-red'ish?

Comment: Looks more orange than red. But, according to [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2013/06/27/designing-the-visual-studio-2013-user-experience.aspx) blog post, you were supposed to like the improvements. :)

Comment: You are right, this increases their distinguishability and recognizability. Still hurts my eyes.

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B0071R3426/ref=as_li_ss_tl?ie=UTF8&camp=1789&creative=390957&creativeASIN=B0071R3426&linkCode=as2&tag=ref_term-20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [Visual Studio Icon Patcher](https://vsip.codeplex.com/) for VS 2012 that [can be made to work with 2013](https://vsip.codeplex.com/discussions/450135)!

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a built-in way to change this. It's really more of a dark orange, though.

Comment: Darn, I guess the wife was right when she complained that I'm color blind ;)

Answer (score 0):

For those having trouble finding the VSIP for VS2013, I was able to download it from [this site](http://www.qingfengju.com/article.asp?id=360)